# Social Auth Best Practice

Tags: javascript, html, socialauth

Which one is the best practice to use social auth: opening a modal window to take data or same page loading?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A model window is better than the page redirect.**

Also when the user is already logged in on social network, you just need to 
show a simple ajax loader. See freelancer.com facebook login for reference.

It terms of implementation. It takes the same amount of efforts. But it has 
visual benefits for the user.

1. The url doesn't change in the address bar.
2. Automatic login with just a simple ajax loader, when the user is already logged in
3. Symbolizes a third party login for the user.
4. In case of an error you are still on your site.

Comment: Thank You for responding to it.
We were confused whether what approach to follow...
This will help a lot.